# Why is Enumerable Min or Max inconsistent between collections of reference and value types?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When dealing with *empty* sequences, I was surprised to find out that the behavior for [min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.95).aspx) or [max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.95).aspx) is different depending on whether the source collection elements are of [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) or of [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2(v=vs.80).aspx):

```
var refCollection = new object[0];
var valCollection = new int[0];
var nullableCollection = new int?[0];

var refMin = refCollection.Min(x => x); // null
var valMin = valCollection.Min(); // InvalidOperationException
var nullableMin = nullableCollection.Min(); // null
```

This difference of behaviors is nicely seen on [.NET Core implementation of Enumerable extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/2c4cac46865d6530cebafdec049466043580c1a6/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1930-L1957).

This, however, is not the case when looking at [Jon Skeet's MinBy extension](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs), for example, which *throws on either case* as I would have expected.

Doesn't the difference in behaviors just cause confusions? Is there any benefit to returning `null` for collections of ref types?

Comment: Just for completeness, add a case `var nullableCollection = new int?[0];`

Comment: Good point! Added a nullable case.

Comment: I'd also like to know why `(new object[0]).Min()` returns `null` and `(new int[0]).Min()` suddenly throws `InvalidOperationException` ([proof](https://ideone.com/9NDIob)). @JonSkeet answer doesn't really answer *why* behavior is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth bearing in mind that nullable types (both nullable value types and reference types) behave differently to non-nullable value types in general when it comes to `Min`: a `null` value is treated as "missing" in general, so it's not unreasonable for the result of "the minimum of only missing values" to be "the missing value".

For example:

```
int?[] nullableInts = new int?[5]; // All values null
int? min = nullableInts.Min(); // No exception, min is null
nullableInts[3] = 2;
min = nullableInts.Min(); // No exception, min is 2
```

For non-nullable value types, there really isn't the option of indicating a "missing value" (unless the return type were changed to always be a nullable type), hence the exception... but this is reasonably easy to spot anyway, as for a non-nullable value type, the only situation where there isn't a minimum is when the source is empty.

(It's possible that `MinBy` should actually behave the same way :)

This is also consistent with the conversions in LINQ to XML:

```
XElement element = null;
int? x = (int?) element; // null
int y = (int) element; // Bang
```

Basically, it does make a certain amount of sense - no option would be consistent with everything.

Comment: I would add that the functioning of `Min()` is consistent to the functioning of SQL `MIN()`... The `MIN()` of an empty set is `NULL`. Clearly a non-nullable value type can't contain `NULL`. So the exception.

Comment: Consistency with SQL behavior seems like a very important point.